# screen goes black when pressing "super" button or clicking the "Show Apps" launcher

Tags: gnome, gui

Every time I press the "super" key or click the "show apps" (tic-tac-toe) button in the task bar, the screen goes completely black.  If I press CTRL-ALT-DELETE the screen will come back (and be on the logout confirmation).

I had a fresh install of 22.04 and it eventually stopped rendering the GUI (black screen).  I upgraded to 23.04 to try to fix it but it persists.

I am running intel graphics:

```
sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for amir: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: CometLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 05
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=3840x2160 resolution=3840,2160 visual=truecolor xres=3840 yres=2160
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:147 memory:6000000000-6000ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I'm not sure where to look for errors.

**Update** If I boot into "safe mode", low graphics, I can press the super button and/or launch the "Show Apps".